# Determine if fragment is nested

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is it possible to determine whether `fragment` is nested or not?

I need this check to `setRetainInstance` in my `BaseFragment` class, which is not possible if fragment is nested

Comment: Did you use `getChildFragmentManager()`?

Comment: Yeah, i figured it out, just checked if `getParentFragment()` is not `null`